# Block concurrent callers and return a single result from an async method

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

I have a method that is called concurrently by several consumers of an `ApiClient` class. I want to block concurrent calls to the method until the first one completes and then short-circuit the remaining calls.

In the pseudocode below, multiple threads may call `RefreshApiTokenAsync()`. I want to prevent all but a single call to the inner `this.GetNewApiTokenAsync()` method. This will avoid the situation where the code detects an expired ApiToken on multiple threads and then tries to refresh it multiple times.

```
public class ApiClient
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ApiTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Call third party API and then detect an out of date API token.
        // The CallThirdPartyApi uses the token in the ApiTokens ConcurrentDictionary
        var result = await CallThirdPartyApi();

        if (result.ApiTokenOutOfDate) {
            await this.RefreshApiTokenAsync();
            result = await CallThirdPartyApi();                
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<string> RefreshApiTokenAsync()
    {
        string newToken = await this.GetNewApiTokenAsync();
        return ApiTokens.AddOrUpdate("ApiToken", newToken, (key, value) => newToken);
    }
}
```

I believe this is considered debouncing, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a `lock()`...

Comment: A lock would prevent multiple threads from calling GetNewApiTokenAsync concurrently, but they would all eventually get called. What I want is for the first call to GetNewApiTokenAsync to happen, but then any other attempt to call the method while it is executing is effectively discarded.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do something like `if (locked) return else lockAndRun()`

Comment: When would you allow new requests again? Also, your return type for `RefreshApiTokenAsync` is incorrect, you return a string but you did not use `Task<string>`

Comment: I fixed the return type. I would allow for new requests after GetNewApiTokenAsync() has returned. The goal is not to try and get more than one new Api token at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can store refresh token task and return it to the callers. After token refreshed callers can continue execution. Here's sample task store:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task>> RefreshTokenTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task>>();
```

And refresh token method can be something like this:

```
private Task RefreshApiTokenAsync()
{
    return RefreshTokenTasks.GetOrAdd("refreshTokenTask", _ => new Lazy<Task>( async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            string newToken = await this.GetNewApiTokenAsync();
            ApiTokens.AddOrUpdate("ApiToken", newToken, (key, value) => newToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            Lazy<Task> refreshTask;
            RefreshTokenTasks.TryRemove("refreshTokenTask", out refreshTask);
        }
    }, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)).Value;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Lazy<>`  to prevent the action from being executed multiple times? I'm referring to the optimistic locking used by concurrent dictionary.

Comment: Yes `Lazy` used to prevent `GetNewApiTokenAsync` to be executed multiple times.

Comment: Makes me wonder if every concurrent dictionary should be wrapped and use `Lazy` instances.

Comment: I don't think so. In this specific case value factory has side effects + "expensive" API call, that's why `Lazy` used